# Crontab not executing Python3 script on AWS EC2 Linux instance

Tags: python, api, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

I can't get a basic python3 script to run using cron on my AWS EC2 Linux instance.

Project structure:

```
ec2-user
  └─ log.txt
  └─ scripts
       └─ test.py
```

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import requests
response = requests.get(url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
response = response.json()
response = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data = response['bpi'])
response.to_csv('s3://my-bucket/test.csv')
```

Cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/scripts/test.py 2>&1 >/home/ec2-user/log.txt
```

Cron appears to be active based on the below output after running `sudo systemctl status crond`:

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-07-29 17:33:54 UTC; 23h ago
Main PID: 3064 (crond)
CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
        └─3064 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

I don't think the problem is with the python script because I can successfully run it in my bash terminal with `python3 ./scripts/test.py`.

Here's what I've tried:

- Various version of shebang line in python script
- Change paths from relative to absolute
- Verified location of python3 is correct

###### ############### EDIT 1 ###############

Checking `/var/log/messages` gives me this:

```
systemd: Created slice User Slice of root.
systemd: Started Session 23 of user root.
systemd: Removed slice User Slice of root.
```

Checking `/var/log/cron` gives me this:

```
CROND[6260]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/scripts/test.py 2>&1 >/home/ec2-user/log.txt)
```

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/syslog`  to see if there is any useful log to debug your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was me not understanding at what level cron was running. I set everything up  at the user level, but cron was running at the root level.

While looking into `/var/log` that @link89 suggested, I noticed the logs referenced `root`. I switched from `ec2-user` to `root` by entering `sudo su` in my bash terminal. Then I ran `/usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/scripts/test.py` in the bash terminal which returned a `ModuleNotFound` error.

I installed all the required python modules at the root level with `sudo pip3 install <module-name>`. I also had to configure my AWS CLI at the root level with `aws configure`. The cron job ran the python script successfully after these changes.

Comment: If you use `crontab -e` to edit cron jobs under `ec2-user`, the cron job should run as the current user. I suppose you edited the cron file directly or used `sudo crontab -e`, which end up running as the `root` user.